# How can I skip the error if vcar already exists?

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple app but there is a problem as you can see in the image I uploaded. But the fact is that they say that vcar isn't defines because it's declared only in the first part of the `if`, but if `i%2 == 0` then it means that vcar has already been created in the first loop. is there a way to skip this error?

```
string[] subs = { "a", "9", "b", "4", "c", "1", "d", "^", "e", "<", "f", "$", "g", "!", "h", "?", "i", "µ", "j", "_", "k", "+", "l", "-", "m", "/", "n", "0", "o", "(", "p", ")", "q", "5", "r", "|", "s", "2", "t", "6", "u", "3", "v", "*", "w", "ç", "x", "7", "y", "8", "z", ">" };

string newMessage = ... // some text

foreach(string character in subs)
{
    i++;
    if (i%2 == 1)
    {
        string vcar = character;
    } else
    {
        string ncar = character;
        newMessage.Replace(vcar, ncar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare `string vcar = string.Empty;` outside the loop? -- Why did you add the `WinForms` 
 tag?

Comment: Removed the irrelevant code and tags from the question. Besides what jimi said, also be aware that `string.Replace` does not make an in-place replacement. You have to call `newMessage = newMessage.Replace(vcar, ncar);`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the scope of a variable when you declare it. Although you will first step in the first part of the if (the true condition actions), ok, you declare a `vcar` variable of type string and assign it a value. This exists only within the `{}` of your `if` statement. `vcar` is not visible (nor exists) within the `else` clause, nor outside the complete if statement.

Summarising, a variable exists only within the `{}` it is declared (and of course, after the line where you declare it). You can read about "scope of a variable" concept as suggested search.

So, as suggested before, you should declare at least `vcar` variable outside the entire `if` statement.